# Glide : No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, android-glide

I use Glide to load images. Some images, like the link below, cannot load, while this image loads well in the browser. Do you know what to do to solve this problem?

https://volleyball.ir/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/IMG_0490-01.jpg

The rest of the images are loaded well, but the images from this site are having problems.

```
 val image_url = "https://volleyball.ir/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/IMG_0490-01.jpg"

 Glide.with(G.context).load(image_url).into(img)
```

logcat :

```
Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
Load failed for [https://volleyball.ir/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/IMG_0490-01.jpg] with dimensions [525x525]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 6 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "volleyball.ir": No address associated with hostname)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 4): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, https://volleyball.ir/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/IMG_0490-01.jpg
There were 3 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

Comment: As error says you may be missing ```annotationProcessor``` in gradle.file

Comment: " No address associated with hostname"  This means that a DNS lookup of the URL you passed in failed.    Since the website does exist, you had a network error on the device of some type, or the website was blocked by your network.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan , I noticed that the host site uses a CDN. Therefore, the image load request is first sent to the CDN and then reaches the final site. Maybe this is the reason why this problem has arisen. In this case, what can be done to solve the problem?